# How can I check for bounce back of email?

Tags: c#, .net, email

I have searched and see many people asking about verifying weather or not an email address is valid - and the overall answer I am getting is 'this is not possible'.

This makes sense, seeing how spam companies would take advantage of it. However, I use MS Outlook client to send my emails manually, and if I send to an invalid email address, I typically receive a 'bounce back' email in response. What's the deal with this? Can't I use these bounce back emails to find the invalid email addresses I have in my system (I am already sending them emails for legitimate reasons and want to see if the email is still valid).

If that's the case, how can I do this in C#?

Comment: not everyone send bounces. but if you want to work with them, then you'll need some way for your app to check the mailbox(es) that the bounces come to, and then create an AI system to parse those bounces for useful information (bounce messages do **NOT** have any kind of standard format), blah blah blah.

Comment: You can avoid the problem mostly by requiring users to opt-in, providing a convenient way to unsubscribe, and removing users for which you *do* get a bounce. There will a certain number of addresses left that once existed bot do not anymore and that do not send bounces, but that's something you have to live with.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. Not all email services send such a "bounce back" email in response to invalid email addresses.

Additionally, a "bounce back" email could theoretically be sent for reasons other than the provided email address not existing, and the fact that you received one doesn't necessarily mean the email address isn't there.

There really isn't a way to determine if a string of characters is a real email address (you can verify whether it is *valid* as an email address, but not whether or not it actually exists).

---

To answer the question you ask in your title, you would have to monitor the return address for incoming e-mail, and then somehow figure out if any received items are "bounce back" messages.